# What is the specific derivation of the speed changes in the two equations from which Einstein originally inferred the relativity of simultaneity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, special-relativity

The two specific equations I’m asking about were stated at an introductory stage in the famous 1905 paper which launched Special Relativity. He didn’t explain how this derivation was arrived at; all I wish to understand is what his direct explanation would have been. The equations were:

$t_B - t_A = r_{AB}/(c - v)$

$t^*_A - t_B = r_{AB}/(c + v)$

These equations referred to a light ray emitted from $A$ at time $t_A$ and then reflected back from $B$ at time $t_B$, returning to $A$ at time $t^*_A$; where $A$ and $B$ are the ends of a rigid rod in a state of linear inertial motion, measured at velocity $v$ relative to its prior state of inertial motion. In this prior state its length was measured as $r_{AB}$. The times referred to  were measured by observers located with clocks co-moving with locations $A$ and $B$ at velocity $v$; these clocks had been synchronised with those established as measuring the time on the rod prior to its state of motion changing to $v$. These events all occurred in empty space where the universal speed of light was assumed always to measure as $c$.

I ask my question about how $c - v$ and $c + v$ are derived for the equations above because, given Einstein’s two postulates, the following pair of equations would seem more appropriate:

$t_B - t_A = r_{AB}/c$

$t^*_A - t_B = r_{AB}/c$

The equivalence of these latter equations would of course have demanded a very different conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of clarity, suppose that in the world reference frame, the rod is moving to the right with velocity $v$, and $A$ is to the left of $B$. Also, let $r'_{AB}$ be the length of the rod in the world reference frame (shorter than in the rod reference frame due to length contraction).

The first two equations you listed refer to the world reference frame. For example, we have
$$t_B - t_A = r'_{AB}/(c - v)$$
because the light ray travels with velocity $c$ and $B$ travels with velocity $v$. Similarly,
$$t^*_A - t_B = r'_{AB}/(c + v)$$
because the light ray travels with velocity $-c$ and $A$ travels with velocity $v$.

The latter two equations you listed refer to the rod reference frame. This demonstrates relativity of simultaneity because in the rod's frame, light would take the same amount of time to go both directions. This is not true in the world reference frame.

Comment: Thank you for making a comment, invjac. But you should note that the equations I quoted are made with reference to the rod frames described by Einstein. Introducing an additional ‘world frame’ into discussion brings confusion rather than clarification.

Comment: @Timm Here, I use the term "world reference frame" for the reference frame of the rod prior to the speed boost of $v$. Apologies if this was confusing.

Comment: Please note, invac, that what is directly under discussion here is the second state of motion of the rod, not the first. The time measures shown in all the equations I quoted are made by observers co-moving with this second state of motion. Also note these observers will measure the speed of light to be c, in accordance with Einstein’s postulates, not c - v.

Comment: Hmm, in that case, I don't know why the equations would be what they are. My answer contains my best guess for what Einstein intended, but I have not read the paper myself.

Comment: I have taken a look at the paper. I think Einstein intends that the observers at each end of the rod synchronize their clocks in the first state of motion of the rod ("stationary state"). The observers then realize that the clocks do not appear to be synchronized in the second state of motion of the rod ("moving state").